# android studio API 19 background issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio

(Android API 19 version) I cant set Background not working

```
 RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout) 
 findViewById(R.id.rlayout_main);
  relativeLayoutMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.docback);
```

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on. Try updating your question with any error messages you may be getting, what debugging steps you have tried, as well as what's happening vs what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: It works in android 6.0 but not in android 4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To set background image to RelativeLayout:**

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayoutMain = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlayout_main);
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourImage); 
relativeLayoutMain.setBackground(drawable);
```

**Otherwise please explain your question.**

Comment: Explain your case please

Comment: I want to add a background, but Android 6.0 is added and API 19 is not added

Comment: then try relativeLayoutMain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

Comment: Thanks I did it My picture is not added because the resolution is too high

Comment: Glad to hear that :)